# Error: Object of type Product is not JSON serializable DJANGO

Tags: json, django

no logro solucionar este error. ALguien tendra idea?
Segun yo estoy enviando bien los datos JSON.
Intente de mil maneras, pero al parecer me doy por vencido y recurro a ustedes.

Este es mi codigo en mi model con error:

```
class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cant = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self, exclude=['sale'])
        item['product'] = self.product.toJSON()
        item['cant'] = format(self.cant, '.2f')
        return item

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Detalle de Venta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Detalle de Ventas'
        default_permissions = ()
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Este es mi codigo en mi view:

```
            elif action == 'get_graph_best_selling_items':
                info2 = []
                for i in SaleDetail.objects.all()[0:20]:
                    info2.append([i.product, i.cant])
                data = {
                    'name': '20 mas vendidos',
                    'type': 'pie',
                    'colorByPoint': True,
                    'data': info2,
                }
```

Tengo el mismo codigo con otro envio que hago mediante JSON y si me funciona, pero no lo logro con el anterior:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    clave = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name='Clave', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Categoría')
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['clave'] = self.get_clave()
        item['category'] = self.category.toJSON()
        return item
```

```
            if action == 'get_graph_stock_products':
                info = []
                for i in Product.objects.filter(stock__gt=0).order_by('-stock')[0:10]:
                    info.append([i.name, i.stock])

                data = {
                    'name': 'Stock de Productos',
                    'type': 'pie',
                    'colorByPoint': True,
                    'data': info,
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Django te está diciendo que no sabe como serializar un objeto de tipo `Producto`, así que pásaselo como diccionario en vez de como instancia de `Producto`:

Reemplaza esta línea:

```
info2.append([i.product, i.cant])
```

Por esta otra:

```
info2.append([i.product.toJSON(), i.cant])
```